# Decomposing 2-sphere into two homeomorphic subspaces

Tags: general-topology

Can a 2-dimensional sphere be decomposed into two disjoint homeomorphic subspaces? If yes, can these subspaces be non-discrete / connected / have some other good properties?

Comment: Why was this question closed?

Comment: @user558840 For lacking any personal effort into trying to find the answer, I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Consider $$X_1=\{(x,y,z)\in S^2: y>0\vee (y=0\wedge x>0)\vee (y=0\wedge x=0\wedge z=1)\}\\X_2=\{(x,y,z)\in S^2: y<0\vee (y=0\wedge x<0)\vee (y=0\wedge x=0\wedge z=-1)\}$$

You can verify that $X_1\cap X_2=\emptyset,\ \,X_1\cup X_2=S^2$ and that $-id|_{X_1}:X_1\to X_2$ is a homeomorphism.

As you can see, they are (locally and globally) path-connected (and homotopic to a point, if you want). 
Of course, you cannot ask for things like compactness.

Comment: What is the role of $z$ ? Is it only there to "split up" the origin ?

Comment: @M.Wind $(x,y,z)$ are the cartesian coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$. $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,0,-1)$ must go somewhere.

Comment: @M.Wind I might phrase "$(x=0\wedge y=0\wedge z=1)$" as "$(x=0\wedge y=0\wedge z>0)$", but it would be the same.

Answer (score 6):

For the $1$-sphere (the points satisfying $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, for simplicity):

[image]

Cut it into two pieces with boundaries $\{(-1, 0), (1, 0)\}$, and give each side exactly one piece of the boundary. Now your homeomorphism is simply a half rotation. The important idea here was giving each half part of the boundary.

You can do something analogous with the $2$-sphere, if you just imagine hard enough :)

For the $2$-sphere (take the unit sphere centered at the origin, again for simplicity):

[image]

Consider the equator $\{(\cos t, \sin t, 0) : t \in [0, 2\pi]\}$ which we'll use to separate our two hemispheres,

[image]

giving the upper half of the sphere ($z > 0$) the part of the boundary where $t \in [\pi, 2\pi),$ and the lower half sphere the part of the boundary with $t \in [0, \pi)$.

Again you have an extremely nice, geometric homeomorphism: rotate one half-turn in the $xy$-plane, and reflect across the $xy$-plane.